# Now this code is not working. I wanted to create 5 student objects (like constructor funcions and classes...) AND write those objects in textarea

Tags: javascript, object, fetch

First time the code worked with separating text in to objects in html. That was great. But my problem was creating objects in javascritp like with constructor and classes and NEW OBJECT for instance... I realy think this would be easy peasy but it is giving me headache. Should i bring back the code that simply wroted separated students in html then try to make "objects" in javascript?

```js
let button = document.getElementById("get-text-btn");
let textArea = document.getElementById("my-text-area");
let loader = document.getElementById("loader");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {

    getData();
});

async function getData() {
  try {
    let response = await fetch('https://v-dresevic.github.io/Advanced-JavaScript-Programming/data/students.txt');
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      throw new Error("Error while reading file.");
    }
    let text = await response.text();
    const template = ['Name', 'Address', 'Number', 'Course'];

    const data = text.split("\n")
      .reduce(makeObj, [])
      .forEach(writeHTML);
 
    function makeObj(prev, itm, idx) {
      if (undefined === prev[Math.floor(idx / 4)]) {
        prev.push({});
      }
      prev[Math.floor(idx / 4)][template[idx % 4]] = itm;
      return prev;
    }

    function writeHTML(obj) {
      const pg = document.createElement('p');
      template.forEach(lbl => {
        const dv = document.createElement('textarea');
        dv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${lbl}: ${obj[lbl]}`));
        pg.appendChild(dv);
      });
      textArea.appendChild(pg);
    }
    } catch (err) {
        textArea.innerHTML = "Fetch problem: " + err.message;
    } 
    finally {
        loader.style.display = "none";
    }

};
```

```css
#loader {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 18px;
    display: none;
}

#loader:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 18px;
    margin: 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #241f1f;
    border-color: #241f1f transparent #241f1f transparent;
    animation: lds-dual-ring 1.2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes lds-dual-ring {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

#my-text-area {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Assignment 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="get-text-btn">Get data</button>
    <div id="loader"></div>
    <textarea id="my-text-area" rows="30"></textarea>


    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to divide the lines into groups of 4. And combining that with the compilation of the list of labels:

```js
let textArea = document.getElementById("my-text-area");

getData();

async function getData() {
  try {
    let response = await fetch('https://v-dresevic.github.io/Advanced-JavaScript-Programming/data/students.txt');
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      throw new Error("Error while reading file.");
    }
    let text = await response.text();
    const template = ['Name', 'Address', 'Number', 'Course'];

    const data = text.split("\n")
      .reduce(makeObj, [])
      .forEach(writeHTML);
 
    function makeObj(prev, itm, idx) {
      if (undefined === prev[Math.floor(idx / 4)]) {
        prev.push({});
      }
      prev[Math.floor(idx / 4)][template[idx % 4]] = itm;
      return prev;
    }

    function writeHTML(obj) {
      const pg = document.createElement('p');
      template.forEach(lbl => {
        const dv = document.createElement('div');
        dv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${lbl}: ${obj[lbl]}`));
        pg.appendChild(dv);
      });
      textArea.appendChild(pg);
    }

  } catch (err) {
    textArea.innerHTML = "Fetch problem: " + err.message;
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="my-text-area"></div>
```

As inspired by the question, this:

```
template[index % template.length]
```

...when applied to an array of items, will consecutively access an item from the template. Typically the template is shorter in length than the array and this expression will loop through the template as many times as needed to apply a template item to every array item.

And to group items, this:

```
arr[Math.floor(index / group_count)]
```

...divides a list of items into groups of `group_count`. The `index` of the group to be divided is divided `/` by the number of items in each group and that—typically a fraction less than 1—is round down.

```
                array: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
                index: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
Math.floor(index / 2): 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3
Math.floor(index / 4): 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

So combining them:

```
arr[Math.floor(index / template.length)][template[index % template.length]]
```

...both compiles the template with the array, and divides the array into groups defined by the template.

`reduce()` is necessary because the input array is longer than the template array, and therefore the output array. The reduction process requires checking and defining array and in this case object components:

```
if (undefined === prev[Math.floor(idx / chunks)]) {
  prev.push({});
}
```

Altogether:

```js
const template = ['a', 'b'], chunks = template.length;

console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].reduce(makeObj, []));

function makeObj(prev, itm, idx) {
  if (undefined === prev[Math.floor(idx / chunks)]) {
    prev.push({});
  }
  prev[Math.floor(idx / chunks)][template[idx % chunks]] = itm;
  return prev;
}
```

Comment: OK Wow. Thank you that is great explaining and great output. But one important thing is left. How can i make an object (5 objects) like a simple objects in javascript?

Comment: @DejanDjordjevic I missed that. Thanks for clarifying. I combined the cool "`template` mapping to the lines" code in the question with the chunking reduce function I wrote previously. And added a function to write the object to HTML. See my updated answer.

Comment: Ok now you got me a bit cofused. The problem is some of these methods i see first time in my life (bc i recently started learning JS). I tried the output came with error in the console: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at getData (script.js:18:27)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (script.js:7:5)
getData @ script.js:18
(anonymous) @ script.js:7

Comment: This is the previous code before started function Getdata:let button = document.getElementById("get-text-btn");
let textArea = document.getElementById("my-text-area");
let loader = document.getElementById("loader");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {

    getData();
});

Comment: @DejanDjordjevic Looks like I changed too much in one go. Now I need your help—I don't know what `let button = document.getElementById("my-text-area")` and `document.getElementById("loader");` and `button.addEventListener("click", function() { getData(); });` refer to. Add that JS code, AND the associated HTML, to your question to help me better understand your problem.

Comment: https://codepen.io/caraklija/pen/xxzGbGW

Comment: I took out the refactoring, so only part of the `try` block is different, and using a DIV instead of a TEXTAREA. — Which brings up the question, do you want the resulting text in a TEXTAREA? Or do you want it "in HTML separated with row break", as you wrote in your question. First I put it in a TEXTAREA but then said you wanted "objects in javascript", I assume JSON. And I interpreted "in HTML separated with row break" as P's and DIV's.

Comment: And people can help you better if you put all the information they need in your question, and not only provide links to it. So, again, I suggest you put the HTML and additional JS *in your question.* That also helps people searching for the same answers you are as they come across this page.